# Rename multiple Columns for multiple Tables in SQL Server 2019 (v15)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have about 700 tables with no data yet, and I need to rename some of their columns names.

First, I need to capitalize the first letter of the column name, so for instance go from `[FIRST NAME]` to `[First Name]`.

Second, I need to get rid of the spaces in between, for example: from `[First Name]` to `FirstName`.

I have created a database with two tables for the purpose of testing.

[image]

I'm using a working function to capitalize the first letter the way I needed.

I have 3 variants of a query and none of them actually working, except for the results.

/* Variant 1 Calling function dbo.CapitalizeFirstLetter */

```
SELECT
    'Exec SP_RENAME ''' + B.NAME + '.' + A.NAME
    + ''', ''' + dbo.CapitalizeFirstLetter(A.NAME)
    + ''', ''COLUMN'''
FROM
    sys.columns A
INNER JOIN
    sys.tables B ON A.OBJECT_ID = B.OBJECT_ID
                 AND OBJECTPROPERTY(b.OBJECT_ID, N'IsUserTable') = 1
WHERE
    system_type_id IN (SELECT system_type_id FROM sys.types)
    AND CHARINDEX(' ', a.NAME) <> 0
ORDER BY 
    b.name
```

/* Variant 2 Calling function dbo.CapitalizeFirstLetter */

```
SELECT 
    'Exec SP_RENAME ''' + B.NAME + '.' + A.NAME
     + ''', ''' + REPLACE(A.NAME, A.NAME, dbo.CapitalizeFirstLetter(A.NAME))
     + ''', ''COLUMN'''
FROM
    sys.columns A
INNER JOIN
    sys.tables B ON A.OBJECT_ID = B.OBJECT_ID
                 AND OBJECTPROPERTY(b.OBJECT_ID, N'IsUserTable') = 1
WHERE
    system_type_id IN (SELECT system_type_id FROM sys.types)
    AND CHARINDEX(' ', a.NAME) <> 0
ORDER BY
    b.name
```

/* Variant 3 Eliminate Space in between */

```
SELECT
    'EXEC SP_RENAME ''' + B.NAME + '.' + A.NAME
     + ''', ''' + REPLACE(A.NAME, ' ', '')
     + ''', ''COLUMN'''
FROM 
    sys.columns A
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables B ON A.OBJECT_ID = B.OBJECT_ID
                 AND OBJECTPROPERTY(b.OBJECT_ID, N'IsUserTable') = 1
WHERE
    system_type_id IN (SELECT system_type_id FROM sys.types)
    AND CHARINDEX(' ', a.NAME) <> 0
ORDER BY 
    b.name
```

[image: The Result for the queries run]

Comment: If this is a once off action then why not just take the results, put them into a new query and execute them?